# create url yii метод Post

Tags: yii

Здраствуйте. Есть ли способ формировать ссылку в yii 1 с передачей даных используя метод пост а не гет? Спасибо.
Пример с использованием гет:

```
     function($data){
 return CHtml::link("Ссылка",Yii::app()->controller
->createUrl("info",array("result_info‌​" => $data->result_info,"site"=>$data->site, 'cod' => $data->result_cod))); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод Post относиться только к форме. Ваша задача решается с помощью формы.

[POST (HTTP)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP))

Comment: а может есть какой то способ скрыть даные в адресной строке?Чтобы просто не видно было что именно передают?

Comment: Опишите полностью задачу и выложите частично код. Придумаю что можно сделать.

Comment: function($data){
           return CHtml::link("Ссылка",Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("info",array("result_info" => $data->result_info,"site"=>$data->site, 'cod' => $data->result_cod)));
        }

Comment: нужно чтобы ,array("result_info‌​"....) не отображался в адресной строке

Comment: Добавь эти строки в вопрос пожалуйста. Не читабельно...

Comment: добавил в вопрос